# How to make twitter login simpler by using PlainOAuth

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, twitpic

I'm using [PlainOAuth](https://github.com/jaanus/PlainOAuth) to post image to twitpic and post message to twitter home page from my iPhone app. Everything is ok, but the way user login to twitter is complex with user.

1. At first, user must select login flow: Pin, URL callback (URL callback seem not working, tested on simulator iOS 4.1)
2. Go to twitter login page to enter username and password.
3. Receiving pin code and return back to previous page to enter pin code.

How can I modify to make them simpler? I mean that can I just need to have a login page that allow user enter username and password (ignore enter pin step)?

I can see a lot of apps that have a very simply login way to twitter. Anyone has solution for this, please help!

Thanks in advance.
Tien

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your app for xAuth with twitter.com. When they allow xAuth, you don't need the step with the pin anymore. xAuth as Twitter defines it is a subset of Twitter's oAuth.

See [using xAuth at dev.twitter.com](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983035/how-to-make-twitter-login-simpler-by-using-plainoauth) oh, thank Heiko! I will send a email to request xAuth right now, but I wonder when I tried using Twiter-OAuth-iPhone library to post a message to twitter home page (no photo to twitpic), I don't need to enter pin code to login.